# elementary OS lacks wakeup from usb controls

Tags: power

I implemented the procedure from this link -> http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/220-ubuntu-resume-usb-hid but would be awesome if this was "out of the box" from elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean wakeup from suspend, please check your BIOS power settings. 
I'm running an Intel NUC and it does wakeup from suspend by hitting a key on the usb keyboard. ... "Out of the box" that is.